# Copy file from another dropbox user using dropbox-js

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-api

i'm currently developing dropbox app that can copy a file from my dropbox account to user who connect to my app. i am using javascipt sdk (dropbox-js).

i do want to copy a file from my dropbox account to another user account.
but i couldn't find any tutorial on how to accieve this, yes i know that there is a method using makeCopyReference and i have done this successfully for file that belong to this user using this code.

```
client.makeCopyReference('/d.txt', function (error, copyref) {
if (error) {
    return handleError(error); // Handle the error.
}

client.copy(copyref, '/test_folder/kamret.txt', function (error, stat) {
    if (error) {
        return handleError(error);  // An error is thrown here!
    }

    $('#resultBox').html(stat.name + " is succesfully copied!");
});
```

});

but i notice that this code only work when i copy file from user root/app folder. but i can not copy file from another user (my dropbox account).

i've read the documentation here https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/stable/guides/getting_started.md and here https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/stable/guides/snippets.md but i cannot find the part that give example on how to get file from another account for refering the file.

thanks in advanced.

Comment: What's the error you're seeing? Copy refs are only valid within the same app, so make sure you're generating the copy ref with the same app that you're using to then copy it to the other user's account.

Comment: thanks for the response, but it is not an error since i dont even know how to try copy from copy ref using this SDK (dropbox-js). now i move to php sdk.

Comment: Your sample code said "An error is thrown here!" I guess that's not the case? Anyway, I can't help you if I don't know what problem you're hitting.